# How to delete rows where cell value = 0?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to speed up some of my current tasks.
The steps I saw best fit

1. duplicate far left (most current) tab
2. copy range I9 to last cell in column with data (including zeros, data above total line)
3. paste values of copied ranged in D9
4. delete/clear cells E9:H24 (if this is done before the copy and paste values of I9, the values in range I9 will be incorrect)
5. delete sheet rows for cells in range D9:last cell in column D with values = 0
6. insert 4 rows below last cell in range A9:lastcellwithdata
7. Go to prior sheet, copy first 4 columns for range A:E with values in column E (almost always last 4-5 rows of data)
8. return to current sheet, paste values (copied in 7) under last cell in column A with data (paste where you inserted the rows, maybe steps 6-8 can be done by copying
   and inserting instead of inserting blank rows first) (This has to be done after step 4 as cells will be pasted over the cells deleted in step 4)
9. for range just pasted in current tab, column C value for entire range changed to current value +1
10. prior sheet, copy range J:M for cells with values in column E
11. current sheet, paste normal copied cells from step 10 to Column J under last cell with data in data range (above total row)

```vb
Public Sub CopySheetAndRename()
    Application.OnKey "^+k", "CopySheetAndRename"
    Dim newName As String
 
    On Error Resume Next
    newName = InputBox("Enter the name for the copied worksheet")
 
    If newName <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Sheets(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = newName
    End If
   
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(3).Row

    Range("I9:I" & lr).Copy
    
    ActiveSheet.Range("D9").PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

    Range("E9:H24").Clear

    Rows("25:29").Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
      CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

I have gotten thru steps 1-4 and step 6.

[image]

Assume P2 is the most current tab, and P3 is the tab that will be created. I took that screenshot after running my macro, I should have deleted that tab before uploading here.

Per the example, all workbooks (150 plus) have the same headers in rows 1-7, a blank row at 8, and the data starting in row 9. All workbooks have data starting from A9:M. The number of rows is inconsistent.

I want to start pulling data from row 9 down to the last column with data before the first blank row (above the totals line).

How do I delete sheet rows from D9:D for all cells with values = 0? This can't delete rows with blank cells, only cells = 0.

Comment: Step5 can be done in 2 ways:
1) loop thought column and delete entire row if cell value = 0 (not "", which is blank).
2) filter column for value 0 and delete visible rows (not "", which is blank).
Steps 7/8 should be done before step5 (to keep the same size of ranges, before copy pasting data and etc... all deletions and additions are better to be done at the very end)

Answer (score 0):

example of the simple loop via column D to delete 0 values (not empty ones).
the main row is

`If ws.Cells(c, 4).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(c, 4).Value <> "" Then`

Note, deleting rows via Loop is always better from the bottom to the top:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro4()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("P3")
Dim c As Long

For c = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row -5 To 2 Step -1 ' note -5 is to offset last row number due to Total/Diff/Balance rows. Or simply use another "clean column" to get the last row number
    If ws.Cells(c, 4).Value = 0 And ws.Cells(c, 4).Value <> "" Then
    Rows(c).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Noob, this appears to work perfectly. Do you by chance know how I could format the last two functions in my vba to be applicable to workbooks with varying amounts of data rows. I should have probably prefaced my op but I am very new to VBA's in general    ''' Range("E9:H24").Clear

Rows("25:29").Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
  CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove '''

Comment: also in the code you recommended for step 5, will I need to update the ">  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("P3")"   P3 part to whatever the current tab each time I plan to use the macro. If it helps understand where Im coming from this macro will need to be ran for 150-ish different stores once a month. So I would pref not want to update the code after I have pushed it out to each of these stores.

Comment: in reply to first Q: you already use dynamic range in the row `Range("I9:I" & lr).Copy` 
read about "finding last row" or dymanic range in VBA, and you will manage to replicate it.

Comment: I have not completely understood the second question... 
If, I got it correct, - you will need to run it on different files/workbooks..
In this case, you will need have them saved in one folder, and create a Loop to open each file and assign `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook` or using filename variable (a more reliable option). Picking/finding the correct Sheet to copy to the new period will be the main challenge, especially if managers name them in a different manner.